# Change CSS of dijit menu in code

Tags: css, dojo

I am creating a dijit menu in code and would like to change the css of menu. Is there a way to do that?

Here is how I create menu

```
ctxMenuForGraphics = new Menu({});
```

I have tried adding class like this but it doesn't work;

```
ctxMenuForGraphics.addClass("myMenu");

.dijitMenu.myMenu {
            background-color: #1e4288;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a an sample fiddle that shows how you can style the `dijit.menu`

[Fiddle Styling dijit.menu.](http://jsfiddle.net/cswing/GCBnF/)